# Is it possible to write a dataframe into 2 files of different type?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

We can use following api to write dataframe into local files.

```
df.write.parquet(path)
df.write.json(path)
```

However, Can I write into a parquet and a json in one time without compute the dataframe twice ?
By the way , I dont want to cache the data in memory, because it's too big.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't cache/persist the dataframe, then it'll will need re-computed for each output format.

Answer (score 0):

We can implement an `org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat` to do such thing.

### DuplicateOutFormat demo

```
/**
 * Very Dangerous Toy Code. DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION.
 */
class DuplicateOutFormat
  extends FileFormat
    with DataSourceRegister
    with Serializable {
  override def inferSchema(sparkSession: SparkSession, options: Map[String, String], files: Seq[FileStatus]): Option[StructType] = {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException()
  }

  override def prepareWrite(sparkSession: SparkSession,
                            job: Job,
                            options: Map[String, String],
                            dataSchema: StructType): OutputWriterFactory = {
    val format1 = options("format1")
    val format2 = options("format2")
    val format1Instance = DataSource.lookupDataSource(format1, sparkSession.sessionState.conf)
      .newInstance().asInstanceOf[FileFormat]
    val format2Instance = DataSource.lookupDataSource(format2, sparkSession.sessionState.conf)
      .newInstance().asInstanceOf[FileFormat]

    val writerFactory1 = format1Instance.prepareWrite(sparkSession, job, options, dataSchema)
    val writerFactory2 = format2Instance.prepareWrite(sparkSession, job, options, dataSchema)

    new OutputWriterFactory {
      override def getFileExtension(context: TaskAttemptContext): String = ".dup"

      override def newInstance(path: String, dataSchema: StructType, context: TaskAttemptContext): OutputWriter = {
        val path1 = path.replace(".dup", writerFactory1.getFileExtension(context))
        val path2 = path.replace(".dup", writerFactory2.getFileExtension(context))
        val writer1 = writerFactory1.newInstance(path1, dataSchema, context)
        val writer2 = writerFactory2.newInstance(path2, dataSchema, context)
        new OutputWriter {
          override def write(row: InternalRow): Unit = {
            writer1.write(row)
            writer2.write(row)
          }

          override def close(): Unit = {
            writer1.close()
            writer2.close()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  override def shortName(): String = "dup"
}
```

### SPI

we should make a SPI file /META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister, content:
com.github.sparkdemo.DuplicateOutFormat.

### demo usage

```
class DuplicateOutFormatTest extends FunSuite {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()
  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  import spark.implicits._

  test("testDuplicateWrite") {
    val data = Array(
      ("k1", "fa", "20210901", 16),
      ("k2", null, "20210902", 15),
      ("k3", "df", "20210903", 14),
      ("k4", null, "20210904", 13)
    )
    val tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "spark-dup-test" + System.nanoTime()
    val df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF("k", "col2", "day", "col4")
    df.write
      .option("format1", "csv")
      .option("format2", "orc")
      .format("dup").save(tempDir)
    df.show(1000, false)
  }

}
```

### WARNING

Spark SQL couple some sth in `DataFrameWriter#saveToV1Source` and other source code, that we can't change. This custom DuplicateOutFormat is just for demo, lacking of test. [Full demo in github](https://github.com/tianzhipeng-git/SparkDuplicateOutFormatDemo).